# PHP: Execution of code after "die" function in PHP/Laravel

Tags: laravel, installation, die

I'm new to PHP and I want to start my laravel project that I copied from another source. I get a 500 error. If I try to debug the index.php in public folder I get an odd behaviour that `die` function did not function if the kernel line in code is there. I don't understand that, I thought that `die` function stops the execution.

```
<?php

die ('hi'); //this die

use Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));

if (file_exists(__DIR__.'/../storage/framework/maintenance.php')) {
    require __DIR__.'/../storage/framework/maintenance.php';
}



require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

//If I comment out kernel line "die" on top doesn't return 'hi'. The response is 500 html code.
//$kernel = $app->make(Kernel::class);
/*
$response = tap($kernel->handle(
    $request = Request::capture()
))->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
*/
```

**EDIT**: the get log from the access log of server is:

```
"GET /index2.php HTTP/2.0" 500 86 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36"
```

I doesn't get any error in error log.
So I have activated PHP-error log. I get this error message:

```
[24-Sep-2020 11:00:39 Europe/Berlin] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_CLASS, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or '$' in /usr/.../inertia/public/index2.php on line 44
```

Comment: Probably the kernel code just makes the whole file invalid so the `die` is never run. Check your server log for the actual error message.

Comment: in the laravel framework index.php is the entry point of laravel.... what do you want to do ?

Comment: @AbdullahAlNoor I want to debug the app, and find out the reason for this 500 response.

Comment: @CherryDT Thank you for your comment. How does it possible that kernel code makes PHP file invalid?

Comment: Please check the error message in your server log, this will probably answer your question. Syntax errors while parsing the file will prevent any code in the file from running. Check the error message to see what exact error it was. Keep in mind that code written for a new PHP version can also be the reason for a syntax error since the old PHP version wouldn't know about new syntaxes introduced later on.

Comment: Sorry for the noob question, but does PHP have server log? Because in `storage/logs/laravel.log` comes no error.

Comment: Laravel's own log file won't help you because Laravel crashes so it won't use this file. You need to check the regular server log. (For example, nginx will write it into `/var/log/nginx/error.log`.) It depends on the webserver how to find it, I cannot give a general answer, you need to check the relevant docs. What is your server environment?

Comment: debian 10 buster

Comment: apache, php 7.4. I'm using ssh, so I doesn't see any control panel.

Comment: Ok please check `/var/log/apache2/error.log`, unless you changed your config this should be the place

Comment: permission denied. I could not read this file. But I will see  in web-panel of web hoster.

Comment: @CherryDT I've edited my question with a log message. Thank you for great idea. But I don't know how to interpert this error message. It doesn't appear in error.log but in access.log

Comment: The access log just shows the requests made to your app, not so interesting for this purpose. But it seems you did find the error after all, that's great and very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is because PHP is not interpreting your code line by line, but it has to first convert it into a suitable format for the runtime engine.

1. Ignore comments
2. Resolve variables, function names, and so forth and create the symbol table
3. Construct the abstract syntax tree of your program
4. Write the bytecode

The server returns 500 code even before code execution starts. The same will happen if you will have any syntax error after the "die();" method. If there is an issue with "use ..." command it will crash during that preparation phase.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand now more, how PHP works. The file will be precompiled as in Java and Co.  So you think the problem is `use`  command.

Comment: @CherryDT you are right, but this answer helped me to understand how PHP works.

Answer (score 2):

So after googling the PHP error message I've found my PHP Version was 5.6 and not 7.4, it was a problem. Thank you all for the help! It helped me a lot.
The `laravel` has .htaccess file in public folder. This file has overriden the PHP-Version to default PHP-Version 5.6.